# using entry.get in a list count in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter

I try to use the ID entry from the GUI to count the similar IDs in the Excel column.

I always get a `0` in the if-loop and red color shows.
But there are similar IDs in the column.

#### My code

```py
l1 = tk.Label(tab2, text="Status Check")
l1.place(x=10, y=10)
l2 = tk.Label(tab2, text="ID")
l2.place(x=10, y=60)

ID = tk.Entry(tab2)
ID.place(x=80, y=60)

l2 = tk.Label(tab2, text="Status")
l2.place(x=10, y=100)

t1 = tk.Entry(tab2)
t1.place(x=80, y=100)

comment = tk.Label(tab2)
comment.place(x=240, y=100)

df = pd.read_excel(r'Excel.xlsx')
IDlist = df['ID'].tolist()
id = ID.get()

def immunity_check():
    d = IDlist.count(id)
    print(d)

    if d >= 2:
        t1.config(bg= "Green")
        comment.configure(text="Fully vaccinated!")
    elif d == 1:
        t1.config(bg= "Yellow")
        comment.configure(text="Vaccinated!")
    else d <= 0:
        t1.config(bg= "Red")
        comment.configure(text="Not vaccinated!")
```

Can anyone give an advice on how to fix it?

Comment: how do you run this code? Usually problem is that `Entry` doesn't work like `input()` - it doesn't wait for your data but it only inform tkinter what widget it should display in window. If you run `.get()` directly after `Entry()` then you get value before it displays it in window , and before you put any data in `Entry` in this windows. You should have some button which run function with .get()` after you put data in `Entry`

Comment: i have a button down to run the function
`button = tk.Button(tab2,text="Check",command=immunity_check)
button.place(x=10,y=180)`

Comment: I don't see this function in your question. And I can't read in your mind. you have to show all details in question. If you have new information then better show in question (not in comment) - it will be more readable, and more people may see it. At this moment I see only `ID.get()` which is NOT in function - so it is executed at start when `Entry` is empty. You have to run it inside function.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with [furas comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70320248/using-entry-get-in-a-list-count-in-python#comment124311906_70320248). Thank him, he solved it.

#### Issue

Currently the code is reading the input from your text-field before button is pressed. Place a `print(id)` behind the `ID.get()` statement and watch console, like:

```py
# GUI initialization omitted for brevity

df = pd.read_excel(r'Excel.xlsx') # read from Excel before button-pressed
IDlist = df['ID'].tolist()

id = ID.get() # get input from text-field before button-pressed
print(id)

# wait for a button press

# below is called on button-press and uses previously read id as argument
def immunity_check():
```

#### Solution

This is how you could solve it. The `id` should be read from text-input **after button was pressed**. So put move statement into the method:

```py
# part 1:  GUI initialization omitted for brevity

# part 2:  define functions to call later
def read_ids():
    df = pd.read_excel(r'Excel.xlsx')
    return df['ID'].tolist()

def immunity_check():
    id = ID.get()  # read the id to search/count
    d = id_list.count(id)
    print(f"occurrences of id '{id}' in list: {d}")

    if d >= 2:
        t1.config(bg= "Green")
        comment.configure(text="Fully vaccinated!")
    elif d == 1:
        t1.config(bg= "Yellow")
        comment.configure(text="Vaccinated!")
    else d <= 0:
        t1.config(bg= "Red")
        comment.configure(text="Not vaccinated!")

# part 3: main starts
id_list = read_ids()

# add button with trigger to function immunity_check()
button = tk.Button(tab2,text="Check",command=immunity_check) button.place(x=10,y=180)
```